# Name conflict in forward declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, c++builder, forward-declaration

I declare a pointer of type `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` in my header. For this I want to use a forward declaration

```
class TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer;
```

Because the `vcl.h` library where this class is described is already included in the `cpp` file.

But if I do this like in the example below, I get an error:

> ambigious name

because the compiler finds the name `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` in my forward declaration and in `System::Sysutils::TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` (which is part of `vcl.h`).

Without my forward declaration, the compiler tells me this type is unknown.
I do not understand, why the compiler can't find the `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` class when I don't use a forward declaration, but if I use one then the compiler has a name conflict.

How can it even find the name in `System::Sysutils::TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer`? This is not included in my header. Like in my example below, my `hpp` file has no includes.

How can I fix this problem?

Sure, I could just include `System::Sysutils` in my header, or change the order of the includes in my `cpp`. But I don't want to include something, when I only need a simple forward declaration.

file.hpp

```
class TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer;

....

TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer* sync;
```

file.cpp

```
#include "file.hpp"
#include <vcl.h>

....
```

Comment: You need to forward declare in the same namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm sorry, but i don't understand what you mean. Can you explain it to me on this example please?

Comment: I can't see, how i'm in a different namespace.

Comment: Just an FYI, there is a much shorter `TMREWSync` typedef available for `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer`

Comment: "*How can it even find the name in `System::Sysutils::TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer`? This is not included in my header. Like in my example below, my hpp file has no includes*" - because the compiler is not compiling the HPP file itself, it is compiling the CPP file. So it first includes your HPP and parses it, then it includes `vcl.h` and parses it, which includes `System.SysUtils.hpp` (amongst others).

Comment: From the description of the problem, it's very likely you are trying to forward declare `::System::Sysutils::TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` and that you are actually forward declaring `::TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `file.hpp`, the forward declaration should be:

```
namespace System {
    namespace Sysutils {
         class TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer;
    }
}
```

And probably all references to the type  (at least in the header file) should have the
fully qualified name `System::Sysutils::TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer`.